# how to edit dynamically mysql data rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to add an extra character into existing data in my database through SQL? I.e., I have these rows and I need to add extra 0 on `zip_codes`.

```
id    | state_abbr | zip_code
16993 | MA         |   1001
16994 | MA         |   1002
16995 | MA         |   1003
```

I want to change it to:

```
id    | state_abbr | zip_code
16993 | MA         |   01001
16994 | MA         |   01002
16995 | MA         |   01003
```

Comment: What is the datatype of zip_code?

Comment: before it was integer, but i changed it into string/varchar

Comment: then check the answer I posted.. should resolve your issue..

Comment: Hitori, if your request is answered / solved, it would be nice if you would honor @SujeetSinha by accepting and / or upvoting his answer. 
You only have to click 1 button and the user, which invested his time and propably tested his solution for your needs, is more than happy.
If you have any questions which you clear with your friends, you will give them also an "thank you", dont you?

Comment: yes sorry. it solved my problem. i was out of my computer that time. sorry again. 

thank you @SujeetSinha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and only if the datatype of column 'zip_code' is varchar (string), the you can use the following SQL to update the values to your need:

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET zip_code = CONCAT('0',zip_code)
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(zip_code) = 4
OR
(zip_code LIKE '0%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(zip_code) < 5)
```

I believe the last OR condition won't make a difference but if that is what suits your needs..

Comment: but if i do that, would it affect all other zip_codes that are correct?

Comment: i want to add '0' to all zip_codes that is only 4 digits, or all US zip_codes that starts with '0', all correct zip_codes are 5 digits.

Comment: check my edit.. If that is what you want, please upvote and mark as answer

Comment: yes. it worked! thank you :) i'm sorry for not upvoting and marking your answer as answer, i am not on my computer that time when i started this question :) but thank you :) it really solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your column type

If you store the `zip_code` as integer, there is no way to add a leading zero in the database.

MySQL Datatype Overviews:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

If you use varchar you can add whatever you want before or after the zip_code.

Example if you use varchar:

```
UPDATE `{tablename}` SET `zip_code` = CONCAT('0', `zip_code`);
```